# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-08-30T06:18:17:698-0600' could not be parsed at index 24

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, jodatime

Here is my `java8` code for this date string `"2016-08-30T06:18:17:698-0600"`

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS'-'XXX");
    String attDate = "2016-08-30T06:18:17:698-0600";
    //attDate = attDate.substring(0, 19);
    System.out.println("####attask date: "+attDate);
    LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(attDate, formatter);
    System.out.println(dt);
```

Using `LocalDate` with truncated date string will solve this issue but I can't simply remove `Time` and use `LocalDate` instead of `LocalDateTime`

Please suggest what's going wrong here. I also need to why your answer will work.

Comment: `could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfYear=30, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2016, OffsetSeconds=-21600, MonthOfYear=8},ISO resolved to 06:18:17.698 of type java.time.format.Parsed` for `YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSXX`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your pattern to `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ` it will print `2016-08-30T06:18:17.123`.

But in your code, the date are with `:` in milliseconds when the correct is `.`.

**Complete code:**

```
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
        String attDate = "2016-08-30T06:18:17.123-0600";
        //attDate = attDate.substring(0, 19);
        System.out.println("####attask date: "+attDate);
        LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(attDate, formatter);
        System.out.println(dt);
```

**Output:**

```
####attask date: 2016-08-30T06:18:17.123-0600
2016-08-30T06:18:17.123
```

Comment: the patter with `:` for milliseconds also worked. As this is the format we get from APIs we have to follow it. Here is the patter that worked `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ`

Answer (score 4):

The minus in the zone offset is part of the zone offset expression, you should not be escaping it as a literal.

Comment: both the formats `YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS-XXX` and `YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS-XXX` didn't work

Comment: You don't need it, `XX` translates to `-0600`already. What you are doing means Java is looking for `"2016-08-30T06:18:17:698--06:00"`.

Comment: By the way, the error message you are getting confirms this.  
At index 24 (i.e. position 25), you have the first `0` of your `0600`. Java thinks that the literal `-` you specify in your patterns must be followed by a `+` or `-` that forms part of the offset. But you immediately provide a number (`0600`), so the parsing fails.